# Calling a sub in VB from a different object instance

Tags: vb.net, function, class

So, i got this Code from another person where i have to do adjustments. There was a whole class doing stuff that all worked fine. Now my task was to rip out a huge chunk - but not all - from the class and put it in a new file and call the code now from the old file. The problem is that the new file doesnt have the object instance it had previously when it was all in the old file. There are so much variables and instances from so many different files. I wanna make it as simple as possible:
I ripped a piece of a class out and put it into a different file. Now i need to let the code run, as it would've never been ripped out in the first place. How can i do this best?

I can provide Code of course, but i doubt that its of any use because its made of so many functions and values adding to each other in different files. But i cannot send the whole project, because then it would still make no sence because specific programs are needed and so on and so forth.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports MadMilkman.Ini

Public Class TransferTxt

    Private iniString As New StringBuilder
    Private Xml As DBIntranet.XmlQmLink.XML
    Private Dt As DataTable
    Private ProgamIni As New ProgramIni
    Private TxtFilename As String = ProgamIni.Path.TempDir & "\transfer.txt"
    Private QMaddress As String
    Private Property XmlQmLink As New DBIntranet.XmlQmLink.XML
    Public Property bStammdaten As New BuildStammdaten(XmlQmLink)

    Private options As New IniOptions With {
        .Encoding = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),
        .KeyDuplicate = IniDuplication.Ignored,
        .SectionDuplicate = IniDuplication.Ignored
    }

    Private Ini As IniFile

    Sub New(xml As DBIntranet.XmlQmLink.XML) 'dt As DataTable)
        Me.Xml = xml
        '  Me.Dt = dt

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' transfer.ini zusammenbauen
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub BuildAndWrite()
        Try
            Me.AddLine("$TEXT (NAM=TXT:transfer)")
            With Xml.QMLINK
                ' STAMMDATEN BAUEN
                Dim Stammdaten = bStammdaten.Build()

                .Gauges.Gauge.First.NominalData.DebugFields()
                    Dim l As New List(Of String) From {
                "PT" & .GaugeTypes.GaugeType.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sCOMMENTS").Substring(0, 4),
                "PT" & .GaugeTypes.GaugeType.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sCOMMENTS")
            }
                    Dim dictPT As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Me.ProgamIni.GetSection(l)
                    If Not dictPT Is Nothing Then

                        For Each kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dictPT
                            Me.AddEntry(kv.Key, .Gauges.Gauge.First.NominalData.SearchFIELD(kv.Value, "-"))
                        Next
                    End If
                End With
                Me.AddLine("$TXTEND")
```

The Line directly below "STAMMDATEN BAUEN" is the call to the stuff that was previously just there. Which is this:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports MadMilkman.Ini

Partial Public Class BuildStammdaten

    Private iniString As New StringBuilder
    Private Xml As DBIntranet.XmlQmLink.XML
    Private Dt As DataTable
    Private ProgamIni As New ProgramIni
    Private TxtFilename As String = ProgamIni.Path.TempDir & "\transfer.txt"
    Private QMaddress As String

    Private options As New IniOptions With {
            .Encoding = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),
            .KeyDuplicate = IniDuplication.Ignored,
            .SectionDuplicate = IniDuplication.Ignored
        }

    Private Ini As IniFile

    Sub New(xml As DBIntranet.XmlQmLink.XML)
        Me.Xml = xml

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' transfer.ini zusammenbauen
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function Build()
        With Xml.QMLINK
            Dim bdakks = .Gauges.Gauge.First.NominalData.SearchFIELD("bDAkkS")
            QMaddress = .Gauges.Gauge.First.NominalData.SearchFIELD("szClientName") + ", " + .Gauges.Gauge.First.NominalData.SearchFIELD("szClientAddress") + ", " + .Gauges.Gauge.First.NominalData.SearchFIELD("szClientCity")
            AddEntry("TESTEST!!", "NICE")
            AddEntry("AuftragsNr", .Gauges.Gauge.First.NominalData.SearchFIELD("szOrderNumber"))
            AddEntry("DAkkS", bdakks)
            AddEntry("Kundennummer", .Clients.Client.SearchFIELD("ALIAS"))
            Dim address As List(Of String) = QMaddress.ToString.Split(", ").ToList
            If address.Count = 4 Then
                Dim addrmerge1 As String = address(0).ToString
                Dim addrmerge2 As String = address(1).ToString + address(2).ToString
                Dim addrmerge3 As String = address(3).ToString
                address.Clear()
                address.Add(addrmerge1.ToString)
                address.Add(addrmerge2.ToString)
                address.Add(addrmerge3.ToString)
            End If
            AddEntry("Auftraggeber", address.FirstOrDefault().Trim)
            AddEntry("Adresse", Me.Flatten(String.Join(",", address.Skip(1).ToArray())).ToString.Trim)

            If address.Count = 3 Then
                Dim strasse As List(Of String) = address.Item(1).Split(" ").ToList
                Dim plz As String = address.Item(2).Trim.Split(" "c)(0)
                AddEntry("Strasse", Flatten(String.Join(" ", strasse.Take(strasse.Count - 1).ToArray())).ToString.Trim)
                AddEntry("StrasseNr", address.Item(1).Trim)
                AddEntry("Nr", strasse.Last)
                AddEntry("PLZOrt", address.Item(2).Replace("/", " ").Trim)
                AddEntry("PLZ", plz)

                If Integer.TryParse(plz, False) And plz.Last() = " " Then
                    AddEntry("Ort", address.Item(2).Replace("/", " ").Trim.Remove(0, 6))
                Else
                    AddEntry("Ort", address.Last.Replace("/", " ").Trim)
                End If
            Else
                AddEntry("Straße", "")
                AddEntry("Nr", "")
                AddEntry("PLZ", "")
                AddEntry("Ort", "")
            End If
            AddEntry("Hersteller", .Gauges.Gauge.First.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sMANUFACTURER"))
            AddEntry("Bezeichnung", .Gauges.Gauge.First.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sMANUFACTURER_DESIGNATION"))
            AddEntry("Seriennummer", .GaugeTypes.GaugeType.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sSERIALNUMBER"))
            AddEntry("Typname", .GaugeTypes.GaugeType.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("TYPENAME"))
            AddEntry("Pruefmitteltypnummer", .GaugeTypes.GaugeType.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sCOMMENTS"))
            AddEntry("Ident", .Gauges.Gauge.First.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sIDENTNUMBER"))
            AddEntry("Barcode", .Gauges.Gauge.First.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sBARCODE"))
            AddEntry("Pruefort", .Gauges.Gauge.First.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sLOCATION", originalValue:=True), "")
            AddEntry("Datum", .Gauges.Gauge.First.MATURITIES.MATURITY.SearchFIELD("dLASTINSPECTION").Replace("/", "."))
            AddEntry("Pruefer", .Users.User.FIRSTNAME & " " & .Users.User.LASTNAME)
            Dim ksNr As String = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",
                                    .Clients.Client.SearchFIELD("ALIAS"),
                                    .GaugeTypes.GaugeType.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sCOMMENTS"),
                                    .Gauges.Gauge.First.ManagementData.SearchFIELD("sSERIALNUMBER"),
                                    Date.Now.Year.ToString.Substring(2, 2))
            AddEntry("KS_Nr", ksNr)
            AddEntry("Pruefintervall", .Gauges.Gauge.First.MATURITIES.MATURITY.SearchFIELD("iINSPECTION_PERIOD_VALUE"))
        End With
        MessageBox.Show("HALLO", "Problem erkannt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Console.Write("TEST!")
        Console.Write(iniString)
        Return iniString
    End Function
    Private Sub AddEntry(key As String, value As String, Optional ignore As String = Nothing)
        If Not value = ignore Then
            ' Werte einfügen mit anschließendem Zeilenumbruch
            iniString.AppendFormat("{0}={1}{2}", key, value, vbCrLf)
        Else
            ' Leere Werte als - einfügen
            iniString.AppendFormat("{0}=-{1}", key, vbCrLf)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Function Flatten(text As Object) As String
        Return text.ToString.Replace(vbCrLf, ", ")
    End Function
End Class
```

If you now think "What on earth is this?" i guess thats the beauty of being new to a project where the original programmer is long gone. Yay.

I tried calling it as Sub or Function. But first i had the program that when calling the class i got an object instance error. Now the function gets called properly, but the first line of the "Build()" Function instantly gives an object instance error again.
When the code was just ... there instead of in another file there were no such issues.

Comment: If you can, it might be best to get both new code and working old code set up to run side-by-side so you can step through them in parallel and see where they unexpectedly diverge in state.

Comment: @Craig it does not work from the very beginning. Because the file in the other class doesnt have to object instance i suppose and it doesnt know what the original class was doing.

Comment: My point is, it seems like you don't fully understand how the old code set up the object instance, and in my experience, the best way to address that is to step through working code and observe what it's doing.

Comment: One idle thought, since you're still talking about trying to set up an instance reference, and assuming the instance is a different type than what you're working with (because otherwise this code absolutely should be a member of that type), maybe you should try setting this up as an extension method?

Comment: @Craig An external method... didnt try that yet. I have to look into it, how that is done though.

Comment: An extension method is called like a member (mostly) but is implemented as a standalone method.  In VB, it will be a public method in a module, with the `<Extension>` attribute.  The first argument is the instance that it will operate on.  Most of Linq is done as extension methods on `IEnumerable(Of T)`.